# Vue multiplying values in a data table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How can I multiply values in a table using Vue.js?
The macro values are given for 100g of the product.
When I type 200g, I would like the values to be doubled, i.e. 318kcal, 12 fat, 48 carbs, 8 protein, 2% iron.
When I type 50g: 79.6kcal, 3 fat, 12 carbs, 2 protein, 0.5 iron etc.

**Demo code** [here](https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/ExNqjjy)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" :items-per-page="5" class="elevation-1" hide-default-footer>

      <template v-slot:item.quantity="{ item }">
        <v-text-field value="" :placeholder="item.quantity" type="number" suffix="g">
        </v-text-field>
      </template>

    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
        { text: 'Quantity', value: 'quantity' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
          quantity: 0,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so we can try and help you fix it? You should be using a computed to calculate these values for you when the user types something in.

Comment: I believe a filter would be a better approach in this case. Manipulating raw data for display is what filters are designed for. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html  ... this is assuming you write a template for each table column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `dessert[].quantity` represented the amount for a single serving size, you could bind the `v-text-field`'s `v-model` to a data property (e.g., named "`userQuantities`") that will be used to calculate a multiplier:

```html
<template v-slot:item.quantity="{ item, index }">
  <v-text-field v-model="userQuantities[index]"></v-text-field>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      userQuantities: []
    }
  }
}
```

Then create a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) (e.g., named "`computedDesserts`") that calculates the nutrition values based on a multiplier, which is the ratio of the user quantity to single serving size:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    computedDesserts() {
      return this.desserts.map((dessert,i) => {
        const qty = this.userQuantities[i] || dessert.quantity
        const multiplier = qty / (dessert.quantity || 1)
        return {
          ...dessert,
          calories: dessert.calories * multiplier,
          fat: dessert.fat * multiplier,
          carbs: dessert.carbs * multiplier,
          protein: dessert.protein * multiplier,
          iron: `${parseInt(dessert.iron) * multiplier}%`,
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And update your template to use `computedDesserts` instead of `desserts`:

```html
<v-data-table :items="computedDesserts">
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MWbNajv?editors=1010)